# Моё имя (–) Леопольд

Tags: тире

Обязательно тире это?

`Моё имя (–) Леопольд.`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Выбор тире зависит от структуры предложения. Тире ставится, если ударением выделена первая часть предложения:

(1) *Кто я? Неужели Вы меня не знаете?!  **Моё Имя – // ЛеопоОльд**.*

(2) ***Мое имя ЛеопОльд,** // можно просто ЛЕо.*

Comment: Мое имя ЛеопОльд. Можно просто ЛЕо. - не нужна запятая, согласования нет никакого. В большинстве примеров пишут через точку;  а через запятую пишут, когда слева только имя: Леопольд Тыквин, можно просто Лео. - чтобы не оставлять одно имя в предложении.

Comment: Откуда правило, сэр?  Это ваши наблюдения по части того, как пишут?)  Я же ставлю запятую по грамматике, семантике и интонации. Здесь же все в порядке. Это БСП,  неоднородное сочинение, присоединительная запятая. Второе предложение распространяет тему первого.

Comment: эмпирический метод.